# Updated Zurb Foundation gem but no changes in my files

Tags: zurb-foundation

I started a project a couple of months ago using Foundation with Sass & Compass. Today I realised that recently the guys form Zurb added some new features so I just uptaded my gem using `gem update zurb-foundation` and althought update was successful I see no changes in my files.

For example, in my _settings.scss file, in the Orbit part, the last part I have goes like:

```
// Slide numbers
// $orbit-slide-number-bg: rgb(0,0,0);
// $orbit-slide-number-font-color: #fff;
// $orbit-slide-number-padding: emCalc(5px);

// Margin for when Orbit is stacked on small screens
// $stack-on-small-margin-bottom: emCalc(20px); // Doesn't quite work yet
```

But if you look at their [Orbit Documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html), the last part is:

```
/* We use thes to controls the style of slide numbers */
$orbit-slide-number-bg: rgba(0,0,0,0);
$orbit-slide-number-font-color: #fff;
$orbit-slide-number-padding: emCalc(5px);

/* Graceful Loading Wrapper and preloader */
$wrapper-class: "slideshow-wrapper";
$preloader-class: "preloader";
```

So I am missing the last part about the loading wrapper and preloader.

I feel there is actually nothing wrong with my project and it's just me who fails to understand how the update should work, so if anyone could please explain I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have found the answer so I'll leave it here in case it helps others.

The idea is that when you update your gem you are actually not updating your project but the Foundation "core" installed in your system (very roughly explained as I am quite ignorant of Ruby). Anyway, for updating your project you need to have your gem up to date first.

Now, for updating your project you need to follow the steps in [Foundation Docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html), where it says "Working with Existing projects", under the heading "Upgrading Foundation Compass projects".

First it's very important that you realise that updating could OVERWRITE your files and make you loose your changes, so read carefully and backup your project before anything.

You have two options:

1) updating only javascripts/image assets. These are file that you have probably not modified unless you are heavily customising the framework. For doing so you should **navigate to your project's folder** and run

```
compass install -r zurb-foundation foundation/upgrade --force
```

where `--force` is forcing the update to overwrite your old files.

2) upgrade Foundation as a whole. Read through the Foundation warning before doing this, basically they advise you to have your own stylesheet with the overrides on it so it doesn't get lost with the update. Again in your project's folder, run

```
compass install -r zurb-foundation foundation
```

Here you can also use `--force` at the end of the sentence.

So, to sum up, updating the foundation gem and updating your project are different things. You can update your gem without that affecting old projects. But to update an existing project you need to upgrade your gem first, then update the project being careful enough so the update doesn't override any changes you may have made.